R frequency table, how do I count observations only if first observation by other variable
I have a table in which I need to count the number of patient having a certain condition, or if not or if no info is available. Ideally, for each patient, there is the same information about cond in each line of the data, but sometimes the data contains errors, as illustrated by the first line that should have cond=1.
I am looking for a solution that allows me to count 0's, 1's and NA's for each patient_id. In the example below this should give me one observation of 0's, two observations of 1's, and 1 observation of NA's.
Have:



patient_id
cond




1
0


1
1


1
1


2
0


2
0


2
0


3



3



4
1


4
1


4
1


4
1



Want:



0's
1's
NA's
999




1
2
1
0



0's is the number of occasions that a patient has only 0's or 0's and NA's.
1's is the number of occasions that a patient has any 1's.
NA's is the number of occasions that a patient has only NA's.
There should not be any cases in which a patient has any other values, but if so, the result should be '999'.
With the function table(df$cond, useNA = "always") I can get the frequency of 1, 0 and NA, but that counts every row and my data has several rows for each patient.

You are applying a function over one vector, based on indices defined in another vector. This is an appropriate use of tapply():

Apply a function to each cell of a ragged array, that is to each (non-empty) group of values or data rows given by a unique combination of the levels of certain factors.

tapply(
    dat$cond,
    dat$patient_id,
    \(x) data.frame(
        zeroes = all(x == 0, na.rm = TRUE) & !all(is.na(x)),
        ones = any(x == 1),
        NAs = all(is.na(x)),
        nineninenine = any(is.na(x)) & !all(is.na(x))
    )
) |>
    do.call(rbind, args = _) |>
    colSums(na.rm = TRUE)

#   zeroes         ones          NAs nineninenine
#        1            2            1            0

I couldn't bring myself to use the non-syntactically valid column names you suggested, but if you really want to you can do so by putting them in backticks, e.g. ``1's = any(x == 1), and adding check.names = FALSE as an argument to data.frame().
Data
dat  <- structure(list(patient_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), cond = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))


I admit those variable names are not optimal, thank you very much for the reply!

A similar approach using tidyverse. First reframe to create a summary variable for each patient based on cond values. After that, you can count up the frequencies for each summary value (0, 1, NA, and 999). The complete afterwards will add 0 counts if not present in the data. Finally, pivot_wider will put into format with column names as 0, 1, etc. and select to put into the same order as example. Like @SamR, I avoided the less-desirable column names (also with gratitude for data).
library(tidyverse)

dat |>
  reframe(
    has_cond = case_when(
      all(is.na(cond)) ~ "na",
      any(cond == 1, na.rm = TRUE) ~ "one",
      all(cond == 0, na.rm = TRUE) ~ "zero",
      .default = "nineninenine"
    ), .by = patient_id
  ) |>
  count(has_cond) |>
  complete(has_cond = c("na", "one", "zero", "nineninenine"), fill = list(n = 0)) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = has_cond, values_from = n) |>
  select(zero, one, na, nineninenine)

Output
   zero   one    na nineninenine
  <int> <int> <int>        <int>
1     1     2     1            0

